# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am running a time series model and in order ot get the predictions I get the error

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Input Code:

```
pred = results.get_prediction(start=pd.to_datetime("2018-09-01"), dynamic=False)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-f3c669d7c5dd> in <module>()
----> 1 pred = results.get_prediction(start=pd.to_datetime("2018-09-01"), dynamic=False)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/sarimax.py in get_prediction(self, start, end, dynamic, index, exog, **kwargs)
   1924         # Handle start, end, dynamic
   1925         _start, _end, _out_of_sample, prediction_index = (
-> 1926             self.model._get_prediction_index(start, end, index, silent=True))
   1927 
   1928         # Handle exogenous parameters

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py in _get_prediction_index(self, start, end, index, silent)
    475         # indexes.
    476         try:
--> 477             start, start_index, start_oos = self._get_index_label_loc(start)
    478         except KeyError:
    479             raise KeyError('The `start` argument could not be matched to a'

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py in _get_index_label_loc(self, key, base_index)
    410         try:
    411             loc, index, index_was_expanded = (
--> 412                 self._get_index_loc(key, base_index))
    413         except KeyError as e:
    414             try:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/base/tsa_model.py in _get_index_loc(self, key, base_index)
    351             # RangeIndex)
    352             try:
--> 353                 index[key]
    354             # We want to raise a KeyError in this case, to keep the exception
    355             # consistent across index types.

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    496 
    497         if is_scalar(key):
--> 498             n = int(key)
    499             if n != key:
    500                 return super_getitem(key)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

But when I run this on dummy dataset it works fine but on to my dataset. I do not know where the issue is.

Comment: What happens if you simply remove `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: KeyError: 'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.' This is the error that i get when i remove pd.to_datetime and pass it as string.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when forecasting monthly data (season=12). The month 09/2018 is represented as "2018-09-01" (including the 01 as day). My (for you shortened) data looked like this:

[image: my data]

Note that my index was a datetime index, but the frequency that it was monthly data was not recognized.
What I did that solved the problem was to re-generate the indexes using pandas:

```
test = test.sort_index() #mine was not always sorted
test.index = (pd.date_range(start=test.index[0], end=test.index[-1], freq='MS')) #MS = month start, which means that the day is set to 01
```

And then the monthly frequency was recognized:

[image]

After that I did not get the

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'

anymore when using results.predict() or results.get_prediction() with Timestamps.
Hope it helps.